# Facebook API getCustomAudiences()

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get all the custom audiences from my account - and I can't get more than 25 audiences, only the top 25.
I am using the 'getCustomAudiences()' function.
Any ideas?

```
$field = array(
CustomAudienceFields::NAME,
CustomAudienceFields::ID);
$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$audiences = $account->getCustomAudiences($field);
foreach ($audiences as $value){
        echo "ID:". $value->id. " Name:".$value->name."<BR>" ;
}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging // You can try and specify a higher `limit`, but you’ll have to see if that specific endpoint supports that.

Comment: I didn't specify any limit, do you have another idea?

Comment: Then the default limit gets used, and that is … 25.

Comment: I've fixed it by adding this line: $audiences->setUseImplicitFetch(true); before the foreach loop.